# Windows clock set back 1 hour every morning even though all auto-settings are off

Tags: windows-10, time, time-zone

I noticed that the clock of my Windows 10 Desktop has been set back one hour every day I boot the system for the first time. The three possible auto-settings afaik for changing the time automatically (automatic setting of time, timezone and summer/winter offset) are off. The timezone has been set correctly during installation and I never touched it. I adjusted the time every morning for the past couple of days.

For some time I had all auto-settings on (or just the adjust time and summer/winter automatically with the timezone CET/Berlin set manually without auto-update) which didn't change the time to the correct value over days and multiple reboots.

I'm running Windows 10 in a DualBoot with Ubuntu 18.10 which has the same settings regarding time (auto-update), timezone (CET/Berlin without auto-update) and summer/winter offset (auto-update) and it works fine there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This phenomenon is caused by management of time on Windows and Ubuntu based on different base timezones. The solution is to make them both manage on the same base.

#### Set Windows's base to UTC

Recommended because Ubuntu displays a warning if it doesn't track UTC

In case you changed it run on Ubuntu

```
timedatectl set-local-rtc 0
```

Then on Windows start `cmd` as admin and run

```
Reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation /v RealTimeIsUniversal /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

and disable the automatic time adjustement on start.

#### Set Ubuntu's base to local time

```
timedatectl set-local-rtc 1 --adjust-system-clock
```

(from http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/05/time-differences-ubuntu-1604-windows-10/)