# Synchronize the clock the same way I do in Settings with a powershell command

Tags: windows-10

On my Windows 10, I need to synchronize my clock at every startup, to do that I go into Settings → Time & Language → Synchronize your clock → Sync now
I am wondering if there is a powershell command to do the same (without elevated privilege)
I found some solutions with `w32tm` but as the service is not started and need elevated privilege I would prefer sticking to the same mechanism I use manually.

Comment: How are you syncing your clock, even by clicking "Sync now", if the service responsible for performing the syncing is started.

Comment: I suppose the click on the "Sync now" button starts the `w32tm` service, because it is started after that and it was not before. What surprised me is I was never asked for elevated privilege.

Comment: Pressing that button does not start the service.  Are you 100% positive your time is actually being synched?  Why exactly is this service, which normally is automatically started when the machine boots, not set to the default configuration?  To answer your question, any commands that might exists, as you expect require the time service to be running. They would just be an interface to w32tm, which will require elevated permissions, which you are unable or not willing to provide to the script.

Comment: @Ramhound At startup my clock is always 1 hour late. The `w32tm` command doesn't work saying the service is not started. Clicking on the "Sync now" button put my clock at the right hour.

Comment: Is your clock one hour later on purpose?  If you have not purposefully configured your device to be an hour off?  That is an extremely easy problem to solve.  You still have not explained the reason the service is not automatically starting though[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1386187/windows-clock-set-back-1-hour-every-morning-even-though-all-auto-settings-are-of/1458248#1458248)

Comment: The clock is not late on purpose and I don't know why my time service is not started at startup. I just found a workaround to fix it: using the "Sync now" button, but having a script doing it for me could be easier.

Comment: Have you tried to set the service to start automatically?  Are you using `RealTimeIsUniversal` by chance?  I am attempting to help you solve the problem you have, that is causing to have a script, as the real problem you have is much easier to solve and does not actually require a script.  This machine part of a active directory domain by chance[?](https://superuser.com/questions/1530760/windows-10-unable-to-time-sync-time-service-is-greyed-out?rq=1)

Comment: The startup time of my Windows Time service is set to Manual (Tigger start). I will switch it to Automatic and see if it fix the problem.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Switching the Windows Time service to Automatic starts the service at startup, but the time is still not sync. The command `w32tm /resync` does the work, but I need elevated privilege.

Comment: You never answered my question about `RealTimeIsUniversal`

Comment: You are right, sorry. I don't have any entry about `RealTimeIsUniversal` in the registry. I am going to try it.

Comment: @Ramhound Set `RealTimeIsUniversal` solved my problem. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: So you ended up enabling or disabling `RealTimeIsUniversal`?

Comment: I ended up by enabling `RealTimeIsUniversal`. I think I had this issue due to my dual-boot with Linux.

Comment: I ended up flagging this question as a duplicate, due to the fact this was very similar to the duplicate question, had I been aware you were dual booting Linux I could have suggested `RealTimeIsUniversal` quicker.